# Subpages Permalinks Issues

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules, sub-menu

my site looks like:

**Page-1** (`page.php`)
... **Subpage-1** (`custom-collection.php`; Custom Post Type)
...... **Filtering Output-Post** (`custom-collection-single.php`)

When I open the filtering output-post by using `/%postname%` for permalinks I get 404 error page.

Some code:

**custom-collection.php**

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'weine', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );

// ============================= WHITEWINE ===============================
if( is_page('147') ) { 

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sorte',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('weisswein')
        )
    )
);
}

// ============================= REDWINE ===============================
```

...

```
// =========================== All WINES ==================================
else {}


$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <a class="item" rel="wine" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('wine-flow', array('class' => 'content')); ?>
    <!-- <div class="label">Slider Label</div> -->
    </a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**custom-collection-single.php**

```
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'single-empty' ); ?>

<?php
    echo '<div class="wein-bottle-thumb">';
    the_post_thumbnail('wine-flow'); 

            echo '...';

?>
```

**The Loop** (loop-single-empty.php)

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**I try to added this to my functions.php**

```
add_action('admin_init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
```

When I use standard permalinks everything works fine for me.
.htaccess: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ...` is active

Thanks for your help.
Ogni

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is all over the place. Lets refer to the visual overview here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview

[image]

Your page is going to use the `page.php` template.

Your custom post type `weine` will use `single-weine.php`

Your custom taxonomy `sorte` ( probably not the best name as it might clash ) will use the template `taxonomy-sorte.php`

So we can expect by default to have a weine post with the title "example" to live at:

```
example.com/weine/example
```

and the `sorte` taxonomy term 'examplesorte' will have its archive at:

```
example.com/sorte/examplesorte
```

What I expect you're trying to do is change it so that there is no `/weine/`, or you think that by using postname that it will change the link of 'weine' posts. This is incorrect, and while there is code out there that may change this, I strongly recommend against this as it introduces dangerous permalink clashes. It's also better if you use the `weine` URL structure to your advantage.

e.g. I would recommend modifying the rewrite base of the `sorte` taxonomy to use `weine/sorte` as it's base, giving you URLs such as:

```
example.com/weine/sorte/examplesorte
```

## A Note On Flushing Rewrites

You need to flush them when your custom post types and taxonomies change, **but** never do it on `admin_init` or `init`. Regenerating rewrite rules is slow and expensive, and by putting it on those hooks, you're massively slowing down your site, and introducing potential bugs and problems.

I would also kill trying to set custom post types parents as that of a normal page. Use the slug in the rewrite base but go no further than that.